# Quotation mark and hyphenation problem when kerning manually

Tags: kerning

I'm trying to get a bit of extra spacing between my quotations and quotation
marks (with a script), but have run into a problem demonstrated by the following
code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\textwidth=1in
\begin{document}
One of these words will be hyphenated.

One of these words will be `hyphenated'.

One of these words will be `\kern1pthyphenated\kern1pt'.

One of these words will be `\hskip1pthyphenated\hskip1pt'.

One of these words willl be `\hskip1pthyphenated\hskip1pt'.

\end{document}
```

Depending on whether I use `\kern` or `\hskip`, I either get no hyphenation or
the mark separated from the quotation.  Is there a solution to this?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TeX will not consider a word for hyphenation unless it is preceded by glue (a skip). A kern will definitely disallow hyphenation.

If you want to kern against the quotes, use

```
`\nolinebreak\hspace{1pt}hyphenated\nolinebreak\hspace{1pt}'
```

The closing quote might be `\kern1pt'`, because a kern not preceded by glue is not a feasible line break point.

Anyway, one point is quite big for a kern.

Glue is considered for a line break only if it is not preceded by a *discardable items*; `\nolinebreak` inserts a penalty, which is discardable (that is, it belongs to the set of items that are thrown away after a line break).

While a penalty *is* among the items considered as feasible line break points, the one inserted by `\nolinebreak` cannot trigger one, because it has the highest possible value 10000.